# Apache Virtual Hosts on different domain names AND ports

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost, domain-name

I use a Ubuntu 16.04 server VM on which I have to configure the following domains:

- maindomain.com:80
- otherport.com:8080

Each domain pointing to the VM's IP, but to a different directory obviously.

I managed to get bind9 to make these domains point to the VM's IP when the VM is the DNS server, and I configured Apache to get the following results:

Good:

- maindomain.com:80 returns maindomain's index
- otherport.com:8080 returns otherport's index

Bad:

- maindomain.com:8080 returns otherport's index
- otherport.com:80 returns maindomain's index

If I put both on port 80, each is separated, but if I do different ports it seems that Apache just cares about the port.

**How could I block the access to maindomain.com:8080 and otherport.com:80?**

*maindomain.com.conf file:*

```
<VirtualHost maindomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName maindomain.com
    ServerAlias www.maindomain.com maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/maindomain"
    <Directory /var/www/html/maindomain>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*otherport.com.conf file:*

```
<VirtualHost otherport.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName otherport.com
    ServerAlias www.otherport.com otherport.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/otherport"
    <Directory /var/www/html/otherport>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: specify `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:8080>` with proper `ServerName`, and also `<VirtualHost *>` as a trap.

Comment: Okay I tried specifying VirtualHost this way, but it still gives the same result. What do you mean by "proper ServerName", what I put in the config is wrong? What is the idea of the "trap"?

Comment: there are [some dns issues](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dns-caveats.html) with domain name as a `<VirtualHost>` parameter. It's about a trivial [name-based config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) with default VirtualHost like `<VirtualHost _default_:*>`. It would work unless VM network config issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done, but I think it's more of a dirty hack than an actual solution. I made two more virtual hosts like so :

*maindomain.com.trap.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName maindomain.com
    ServerAlias www.maindomain.com maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/maindomain"
    <Directory /var/www/html/maindomain>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The other one having the names and port switched.
By the way, I left `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:8080>` in the first two .conf files I mentioned in my first post.